How to get CLI arguments in Assembly language without libc?
I wanted to print out first command line argument in x86_64 Assembly on Linux, but I have had hard time getting value of it. For clarification: commands I use to compile this are as -o args.o args.s -g and ld -o args args.o -g
Here's the code:
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
        movq (%rsi), %rsi # that gives segfault which makes sense since value in %rsi was zero and 
                          # it tried to access value on address zero, which gives segfault
        movq $5, %rdx 
        movq $1, %rax
        movq $1, %rdi
        syscall
        # exit
        movq $60, %rax
        movq $0, %rdi
        syscall

This code is wrong. It would be correct if I used C library and it would be in main since then %rsi would contain **argv[], but I choose to not use libc and write my own _start.
So my question is, where is argv stored? How do I get the address of it (if it is stored in memory)?
P.S. This code has multiple issues, for example: even if it would get address of argv correctly it still would print out path from where this program was executed instead of actual CLI argument, or that if argument is bigger that 5 in length the program would fail, but I didn't fix those here the for the sake of keeping things simple.
